# Show that $f(x)$, given by $f(x)=x$ for rational and $f(x)=-x$ for irrational numbers, is continuous at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, irrational-numbers, epsilon-delta, rational-numbers

I came across the following function $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x, & x \in \mathbb{Q}, \\
-x, & x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}. 
\end{cases}$$ It is claimed that $f(x)$ is continuous at zero. I want to be able to prove this.

So let $\varepsilon >0$ and consider that \begin{eqnarray*}
\left| f(x) - f(0) \right| &=& \left| f(x) -0 \right| = \left| f(x) \right|. 
\end{eqnarray*} Now at any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a rational number $q$ such that $\left| x - q \right| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and similarly for an irrational number. I assume this is how the proof is formulated, but can't seem to structure it.

Answer (score 4):

Fix $\epsilon>0$. Taking $\delta=\epsilon$ we have 
$$
|x|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(0)|=|x|<\epsilon
$$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**: $|f(x)| = |x|$, so $|f(x)-f(0)| = |x-0| = |x|$.